# It has been around about xxx years

Tags: grammar

> Our house has been around **about** 40 years.

Or

> Our house has been around 40 years.

Which is correct, grammatically?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're interested in this exact phrasing? Neither option is particularly idiomatic. We generally don't refer to houses being "around"... more "The house was built..." Are you specifically trying to use this phrasing?

Comment: Ops I missed adding **"for”**!. My bad.

Comment: @JohnArvin The first sentence sounds fine to me.  The "for" is optional.   The second sentence is fine if if you include the "for", *"Our house has been around for 40 years"*.  However I will agree with Catija that it's a little unusual to say something like a *house* (or other structure) has "been around", because that suggests at least sometimes it goes away and then comes back.

Answer (score 2):

I don't really see either of them as being great options. I really want to add "for" to both versions. I'm changing the example, though, because I think that the optimal phrasing for that example is something else entirely:

> The concept has been around *for* about 30 years.
>   The concept has been around *for* 30 years.

In this case, "has been around" means "has existed". So, if we make that substitution:

> The concept has existed [for] about 30 years.

This would probably pass as acceptable but I'd still probably prefer to add "for".

> The concept has existed [for] 30 years.

The only difference here is that you're being precise in the amount of time. In the first version, "about" means "in the vicinity of" or "around" - which would be confusing if used in both senses:

> The concept has been around [for] around 30 years.

But it's still correct, if messy.

Without "about", you're *generally* implying that it's been *exactly* 30 years. Not 29 or 32... 30. This can be a bit open to interpretation but I argue that without "about" the range of years is more confined than with it.

That said, without "for" it's more conversational, not necessarily *incorrect*.

---

When you're talking about a house, you're better served saying something more like

> Our house was built about 40 years ago.

Comment: As I have written above, I missed adding ''for''. So would it be correct now to say: **Our house has been around for approximately 40 years.** the key thing here is I wanted to use ''has been around'' as an alternative for ''built'' or ''existed'', they are very commonly used and I wanted to ''up the game''. Hope you catch my drift here man, is the bold sentence now correct?

Comment: I'm not a man. And, I'm sorry... but "has been around" to me sounds like the house was moved from somewhere else to where it currently is... though, for some reason, "has been around since the 80s" doesn't bug me as much.

Comment: Still, I can use the last highlighted sentence you have put in, I see you're not a man, thx helpful mother.

Comment: For what it's worth, I hear nothing at all wrong with "has been around" when it comes to buildings, businesses, or anything else. It may have something to do with regional idioms, but it's certainly something that I hear quite often. In fact, it sounds more natural to me than other ways of phrasing it. (I'm from Ontario, Canada.) However, I would not use it in formal speech.

Comment: I see, that makes sense, both Catija and Andrew are from the U.S.A. so partly their answer is idiomatic