# What is the difference between milling around and milling about?

Tags: word-usage, verbs, phrasal-verbs

I have looked for the difference between these phrasal verbs in the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/mill-around-about), [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-thesaurus/mill-about-or-around), [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mill), among others, and they all seem to indicate there is no difference between one and the other.

Would a native speaker use these phrasal verbs indistinctively? If not, in what situations is one preferred over the other?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [“About” vs. “around”.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/26666/about-vs-around) Also [Staggering around/about {on} the roof](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/256361/staggering-around-about-on-the-roof) and perhaps [It has been around about xxx years](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/164489/it-has-been-around-about-xxx-years?rq=1).

Comment: Per [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=milling+around+outside%2Cmilling+about+outside&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmilling%20around%20outside%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmilling%20about%20outside%3B%2Cc0), both forms are perfectly common. I don't think the choice of adverb makes any difference at all to the intended or perceived meaning.

Comment: I, as a Canadian native speaker, find "mill about" much more natural than "mill around", though both sound correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of these expressions are used interchangeably and would be understood to have the same meaning. "Milling (or wandering, walking) around/about" both suggest casually moving within an area. In general use, neither suggest a particular route or method.

However, "around" can be used to suggest a broadly circular route following the outer perimeter of something. For example "I walked around the block" would be taken to mean someone walked a single route that took them around a block of buildings and they ended where they began. But, words like "milling" and "wandering" imply some degree of aimlessness, so used with those, this would have a different meaning. "Wandering around the block" sounds like someone just moving randomly within the area.